# How can I evaluate the integral :

Tags: integration, analysis

How can evaluate this integral any suggestions 
Thanks in advance

> $$\int_0^{\dfrac\pi2}\dfrac{\cos x}{3 + \cos^2x}\,\mathrm dx$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$, and if $u=\sin x$ then $du=\cos x dx $

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the warm welcome!  The solution is pretty good Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With $u=\sin x$, $du=\cos x\,dx$, so

${\Large\int} _0^{\pi/2} \dfrac {\cos x}{3+\cos^2 x} dx={\Large\int}_0^{\pi/2}\dfrac{\cos x \,dx}{4-\sin^2x}={\Large\int}_0^1\dfrac{du}{4-u^2},$

since $\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$.

Can you take it from here?